# How to upload an image to remote server using SMB protocol in java which works both for windows and linux?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to upload an image through SMB protocol but unable to connect to remote server.
Following is my code:

```
           String user = "admin";
           String pass ="admin";
           byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(resourceDTOReq.getImageData());

            String path="smb://ip/sharedfolderName/";
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);
            SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
            SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
            smbfos.write(imageBytes);
            System.out.println("Upload completed!");
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/172.20.2.198
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.ssn139(SmbTransport.java:196)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:249)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:322)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me get through this, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for linux users:

set `server min protocol = NT1` in your [global] section of samba config in samba server (e.g.  /etc/samba/smb.conf)

Then restart samba service with `sudo service smbd restart`

You can find complete solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1265990/1755694)